# Delete all Ubuntu partitions and reinstall again

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, windows

I have messes up ubuntu twice, and reinstalled it again after that. THis has created two ubuntu partions on my drive. Is it safe to remove all these partitions from windows, and then reinstall using a live CD? WIll i be able to boot windows and ubuntu both from GRUB again?

Comment: Better to use gparted from live installer. Generally use Windows for Windows fixes & Linux for Linux fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `Windows` on third partition then should be ok delete these two partitions and create just one. When you will install `Ubuntu` on that second one with live CD, `GRUB` will install with it too. So `GRUB` should autodetect your `Windows` on your first partition and let you choose what to boot on computer startup.

Comment: It worked! Just wanted to ask, if I install debian too now (on a seperate disk partition), will GRUB detect all 3 OSs?(Debian, Ubuntu, and WIndows)

Comment: It should detect all three. The Debian installer will install grub over the version of grub Ubuntu installed, i.e. placing Debian first on the list. But, there is documentation on changing the order. If for some reason all are not on the list, you can boot up Debian. Then run sudo update-grub. If for some reason this doesn't work, you can burn boot-repair-disk.

Comment: I have had an issue before where I had grub 1.9, and then I installed an OS on another partition with v. 2. Version 2 will place itself first, but then if you select Windows, it takes you to grub 1.9. Then you boot into Windows. So, you might want to check on making sure it is the same version of grub. Regardless, if it is not, I think boot-repair-disk would fix that.